# What is the value per user in purchase revenue metric in Firebase A/B test

Tags: firebase

We ran a Firebase experiment having the **purchase revenue** user property as a secondary metric. After some time the **value per user** metric started showing these huge values.

The attached image shows the **purchase revenue** metric having total revenue of $2k and the number of users is 10k in each group. Still the estimate for the **value per user** is $170k-$300k, which doesn't make any sense.

What is the **value per user** estimate? Should it be the **total value** divided by the number of users or is it something else?

The client app platform is iOS built in Unity3d with Firebase Unity SDK. The purchases are for subscription products.

[image: Screenshot of the purchase revenue metric results in Firebase A/B test console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy in the results shown in the question were caused by a bug in the Firebase console. The bug has now been fixed and the correct **value per user** seems to be the **total value** divided by the number of users.

Comment: I'm still seeing this discrepancy

Comment: I contacted Firebase support by email and they were very helpful, although it took a few days to get a reply.

Comment: I also contacted Firebase support. After a long discussion they confirmed that it's a bug but didn't commit to any date for deploying a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Which platform / SDK version are you on?